# Why is Foundation.h not imported in the standard Xcode templates?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios

I just noticed that when I create iPhone application using standard templates in Xcode (View Based Application, Window based application etc) the header files only import UIKit.h (and not Foundation.h). So if the Foundation.h file is not imported, how can one use Foundation classes like NSString, NSArray etc in the program ? Shouldn't it be throwing an error?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is imported in the precompiled header file (extension `.pch`) in your project.

```
#ifdef __OBJC__
    #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#endif
```

As to why `UIKit.h` appears to have two import lines per file since it also shows up above, though, I'm not too sure. It shouldn't matter anyway, as the second `#import` line won't cause UIKit to be included again if it's already included in the precompiled header file.

Comment: Well then the UIKit/UIKit.h is also imported in the precompiled headers. Why is it imported in our header files again?

Answer (score 2):

If you take a look at some of the individual UIKit headers, they import Foundation themselves. As BoltClock noted, it's also in the standard .pch

The reason that it *can* be put in all these places is mentioned in ["The Objective-C Programming Language"](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocDefiningClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH12-TPXREF123):

> This directive is identical to #include, except that it makes sure that the same file is never included more than once. It’s therefore preferred and is used in place of #include in code examples throughout Objective-C–based documentation.

You want to make sure that every file that needs access to the symbols defined in Foundation has them. The reason it's repeated is that it helps with reading and understanding the code; it says "This code relies on the stuff that's in this header".

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the template files are designed to work with or without precompiled headers, so they import the header files they use. If you create a subclass of `NSObject` the template file *will* import `Foundation`. If you create a subclass of a `UIKit` object the `UIKit` header will be imported.

OK, so why can you use `Foundation` classes like `NSString` when only `UIKit` is imported. Well nearly all of the `UIKit` headers import `Foundation.h`!

Hope this make sense.